# Problem with IP Camera Streaming with Flask Web and opencv

Tags: python

I have a problem with my IP camera trying to streaming in Flask Web using opencv. In my html page shows the camera streaming window but it capture a frame every 2-3 minutes...
i got this error: `[h264 @ 0x130e6e0] error while decoding MB 14 2, bytestream -15`

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.105:554/user=admin_password=12345_channe0_stream=0.sdp')

def gen_frames():  # generate frame by frame from camera
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  # concat frame one by one and show result

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen_frames(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Comment: Please can anyone help me ?

Comment: Did you solve this im facing the same problem